# Usage of より at end of sentence?

Tags: usage, nuances, particle-より, context

Just wondering a little bit about the mechanics of より in this sentence. The context as far as I can tell is that someone is saying they are better at doing Laundry and cleaning when compared to their sister.

> 掃除洗濯も得意ですよ 姉様より

より here is simply being used to compare but I've not seen it used as a sentence ending before and would just like to confirm my feeling is correct and what's happening here is as the comparison is so obvious given the prior context the last sentence is abbreviated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 掃除洗濯も得意ですよ 姉様より

Considering the provided context, it's a colloquial 倒置 (inversion/anastrophe) of:

> 掃除洗濯も、姉さまより得意ですよ。
> (or 姉さまより掃除洗濯も得意ですよ。)

This kind of 倒置 frequently occurs in daily colloquial speech in real life.

For examples of 倒置 in conversation:

- [Function of に and meaning of ものだ in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17616/9831)
- [Understanding もな](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/91309/9831)
- [Two に with 行かれて](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58185/9831)